# Counting Recursive Calls - Towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am working on a problem dealing with a variation on the towers of Hanoi problem, one where you can only move to adjacent pegs and we are limited to a 3 pegs problem. I have gotten the code to print out the moves necessary for the number of discs but I cannot figure out how to print the number of recursive calls.

```
def adjacent_hanoi(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg):
"""
Given the number of discs in Adjacent-Peg Tower of Hanoi:
1. Prints each move necessary to solve the puzzle (minimum number of moves)
2. Returns the total number of moves required

For this problem, discs should always start on the first peg and
end on the last peg.

num_discs: an integer number of discs
start_peg: starting peg
end_peg: ending peg
returns: an integer number of moves
"""

if num_discs > 0:
    adjacent_hanoi(num_discs-1, start_peg, end_peg)
    print "Move disc", num_discs, "from peg", start_peg, "to peg", 2
    adjacent_hanoi(num_discs-1, end_peg, start_peg)
    print "Move disc", num_discs, "from peg", 2 , "to peg", end_peg
    adjacent_hanoi(num_discs-1, start_peg, end_peg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a decorator!

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.count = 0
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.count += 1
        return self.func(*args)
@Counter
def your_function():
    return "Hello"

for i in range(10):
     print your_function()

print your_function.count #=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter which is a global variable. At the beginning of your function increase it by 1.

```
recursionCounter = 0

def functionToTrack:
    recursionCounter += 1
    #the rest of your code...
```

If you just want to track levels of recursion store it and reset `recursionCounter`  to 0 each time you call from outside the function.

```
functionToTrack()
firstCallRecursion = recursionCounter
recursionCounter = 0
functionToTrack()
secondCallRecursion = recursionCounter
recursionCounter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new parameter, lets call it `count`.

```
def adjacent_hanoi(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg, count):
```

You can increment it each recursive call.

Another way is to add a global variable and just increment it. I'd do it this way if it's nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding an additional parameter to your function as an incremental counter:

```
def adjacent_hanoi(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg, count=0):
    #do something with num_discs, start_peg, and end_peg
    count += 1
    print count
    return adjacent_hanoi(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a mathematical sequence.

just make a helper method

```
hanoi_recurse(num_discs, start, end)
```

which does the same thing as the first method

now your code looks like

```
def adjacent_hanoi(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg):
    adjacent_hanoi_recurse(num_discs, start_peg, end_peg)
    print (3 ** num_discs) - 1
```